# Postman API testing: Assertion of value datatype within POST response not validating correctly

Tags: postman, assertion

I am trying to assert value datatypes against a POST response but I am getting a success response for incorrect datatypes, i.e. my assertion for a number is a success when the value is a string.

This is the response to the POST:

```json
  [
    {
        "customerActivity": [
            {
                "CustomerActivity": {
                    "Client": {
                        "clientCode": "TEST001",
                        "creditGroup": null
                    },
                    "Cash": 4321,
                    "status": "SUCCESS",
                    "statusDetails": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "CustomerActivity": {
                    "Client": {
                        "clientCode": "TEST002",
                        "creditGroup": null
                    },
                    "Cash": 1234,
                    "status": "SUCCESS",
                    "statusDetails": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my test to check that the value for clientCode is a number, which results in a Success even though the value is a string (it should be a string, I want the test to fail):

```js
  let jsonData = pm.response.json()
  
  pm.test("clientCode is a number", () => {
      _.each(jsonData.customerActivity, (item) => {
          pm.expect(item.clientCode).to.be.an("number");
      })
  })
```

I have tried various ways to get to clientCode and I either get the same Success or "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined".

I am a noob so I'm sure it's dead simple but I really would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes here:

- Response is an array, you have to define `index` to get nested json.

`jsonData.customerActivity` -->`jsonData[0].customerActivity`

- from `customerActivity` to `clientCode`, you missed 2 levels.

`item.clientCode` --> `item.CustomerActivity.Client.clientCode`

The correct code is:

```js
let jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test("clientCode is a number", () => {
    _.each(jsonData[0].customerActivity, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.CustomerActivity.Client.clientCode).to.be.an("number");
    })
})
```